# Question on security of hose bib

Tags: siding, hose

[image]

I have only turned on the water for this bib once, but am afraid to use it regularly in the event that it has a leak on the inside. Additionally, the bib is unsecured to the wall. I have seen this [post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/129307/how-can-i-secure-this-faucet-the-pipe-is-not-secured-inside-the-wall?newreg=64e3f5b6930a46ed9191d20d7dd2a20d), however since my home has the siding, I am unsure of how best to proceed with securing it. Any thoughts and advice would be welcomed.

Comment: Is that the normal position of the faucet or have you pulled it out?

Comment: Most houses have siding of some sort and the hose bib is attached anyway.

Comment: That is pulled all the way out in order to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

On that faucet it appears that the shutoff point is on the exterior side of the wall as opposed to a freezeless faucet which has the shutoff mechanism inside the wall. Therefore, if it's leaking inside, it will leak whether the faucet is turned on or not.
It's hard to tell from the pic but it looks like there is a threaded connection just ouside your siding. If that leaks the water could travel back along the supply line into the wall. But you would be able to see that from the exterior.
It's always a good idea to secure the bib to the siding. Unless you build a box on the exterior wall the only way to do it is to shorten the supply line coming out of the wall. The pipe may have some play in it back into the wall. If that isn't enough and you have access inside you can go that route. Also you might be able to remove the white fitting if it's not integral to its functioning (flow restrictor, etc.). If you can get the bib within 3/4" of the siding you can back the bib with trim and fasten it that way.

Comment: It looks like it is pulled all the way out. The hose bib has two slots ar 3 and 9 o'clock positions that will normally be screwed  to the siding material or ideally to at least on stud on one side a yhe siding or backing material on the other.     There is one screw visible at the 3 o'clock  position.   If the other is missing the hose bib might have wiggled loose.     If you are in the freezing parts of the country, you might want to get this hose bib replaced with on where the water is shut off in the conditioned space of you basement aka freeze less hose bib.

Comment: So, the water shut off is definitely inside. To be specific, it’s in the utility closet. TBH, we purchased the home in January and moved in in March and yesterday was the first time I turned the water on out of fear of there being an internal leak that was cause by how unsecure it is. The only thing I noticed was an unscrewed valve directly after the shut off that sprayed water everywhere until I tightened it fully

Comment: I think we're talking about different shutoffs. It wasn't clear that there is one in the utility closet. That shutoff is apparently to isolate the outside faucet in the winter to prevent freezing. Can you edit and post a picture of the shutoff in the utility closet.